# How do I change a series of graphs by a button in excel

Tags: excel, dashboard

I'm building a dashboard on excel and want to change the graphs when i click on a button (for each department). Anyone know how to make this possible?

Any response is greatly needed and appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select case** for departments and use this code -

syntax - *Sheetname*.ChartObjects(*chartname*).Chart.ChartType = *charttype number*

```
e.g. Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.ChartType = 4
```

to get all the numbers, you can create a dummy chart and print the number using msgbox - e.g. msgbox sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart1).Chart.ChartType

Let me know if you require me to write the entire code for you.

Hope this helps!